# Converting a NSMutableString to a float value

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsmutablestring

In my app I am getting values from a bunch of sliders and converting them to a NSMutableString in the AppDelegate. However, I need to recall these values later on so I can do some calculations with them, but I can't reconvert these values back to a float, I just get 0 every time. What can I do to convert the NSMutableString to a float value?

Here is my code for the view controller that is trying to get the NSMutable strings from the delegate, convert them, and do a calculation.

```
-(IBAction)sliderValue:(id)sender {

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];



float x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20,compat;



x1 = [appDelegate.x1 floatValue];
x2 = [appDelegate.x2 floatValue];
x3 = [appDelegate.x3 floatValue];
x4 = [appDelegate.x4 floatValue];
x5 = [appDelegate.x5 floatValue];
x6 = [appDelegate.x6 floatValue];
x7 = [appDelegate.x7 floatValue];
x8 = [appDelegate.x8 floatValue];
x9 = [appDelegate.x9 floatValue];
x10 = [appDelegate.x10 floatValue];
x11 = [appDelegate.x11 floatValue];
x12 = [appDelegate.x12 floatValue];
x13 = [appDelegate.x13 floatValue];
x14 = [appDelegate.x14 floatValue];
x15 = [appDelegate.x15 floatValue];
x16 = [appDelegate.x16 floatValue];
x17 = [appDelegate.x17 floatValue];
x18 = [appDelegate.x18 floatValue];
x19 = [appDelegate.x19 floatValue];
x20 = [appDelegate.x20 floatValue];

compat = (40-(fabsf(x1-x11)+fabsf(x3-x13)+fabsf(x6-x16)+fabsf(x8-x18))+(x2+x5+x7+x10+x12+x15+x17+x20)*(1-fabsf(x10-x20)/10)/2+(2-fabsf(x4-x14)/5)*(x5+x15)/2);


NSMutableString *strAnswer = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Your Compatibility is "];
NSString *score = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",x2];


[strAnswer appendString:score];
[strAnswer appendString:@" % "];
result.text = appDelegate.x2;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Results Are IN!!" message:strAnswer delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[alert show];
```

}

How exactly would I implement the NSScanner method is here?

Comment: NSMutableString  inherits from NSString!

Comment: Don't mix all your question into one thread. Edit about NSScanner should be a separate question.

Comment: float x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20,compat; looks very very wrong, use a collection...

Answer (score 2):

Use the floatValue NSString method or a [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-SW2), which is more powerful and flexible. I personally prefer the latter as floatValue returns 0.0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number. So you can't distinguish between `@"0.0"` and `@"completegarbage"`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str setString:@"123.4"];

float f = [str floatValue];
```